# Can we add Virtual Background for Twilio in iOS?

Tags: ios, video, twilio

Working on Twilio video calling app I need virtual background for video it is possible in Twilio ? can any one help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"I need virtual background for video"_ what **exactly** is a virtual background for video? A video is made of multiple pictures called frames so tell us, for each frame, what do you want to do with the pixels of that image?

Comment: @VC.One need to change different backgrounds like zoom video virtual background.

Answer (score 0):

Not [anything](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-react/issues/287) built in to do this.

Comment: it is possible to write custom video class?